# Copy selected text android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm new to android development. I want to copy selected text in webview to clipboard. My code goes like this. it gives error `v` is not declared variable and CLIPBOARD_SERVICE also gives error. I dont understand what is `yourtextview` in this. Anyone here can help me to achieve copy to clipboard with this code.

```
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                System.out.println("Action Item Clicked Mode");
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.copy:
                    TextView yourTextView = (TextView) v;
                       ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
                       clipboard.setText(yourTextView.getText());
                    }
    }
```

is there any other way to achieve copy selected text to clipboard inside this case in my code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create user defined method.

Below is the complete running example.

Hopes it helps you

http://devemat-androidprogramming.blogspot.in/2011/06/selecting-text-with-webview.html

Comment: it doesn't work in android 4.x. You have any other workaround